# Clustering Android GoogleMap is very slow

Tags: android, google-maps

I have integrated clustering in my app. Adding custom image for single item in onBeforeClusterItemRendered method causes app to stuck for sometime. Issue is only in Android 8 devices.

```
override fun onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item: MarkerItem?, markerOptions: MarkerOptions?) {
        val iconType = getMarkerIcon(item!!.mapObjectType, item!!.markerType)

        setMarkerIcon(mapObjectSelection, item.mapObjectType, markerOptions, iconType, 0, false)



    }




 private fun setMarkerIcon(currentTableSelection: Int, mapObjectType: Int, markerOptions: MarkerOptions?, iconType: Int, markerCount: Int, isClusterIcon: Boolean) {

 if (isClusterIcon) {
            val icon = mMapIconGenerator.makeIcon(iconType, tempMarkerCount)
            markerOptions?.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon))
        } else {

            var bitmap = mapIcons[iconType]

            if(null == bitmap){
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.resources,iconType)
                mapIcons[iconType] = bitmap
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom image size was very large that was causing the stuck on clustering. solved by reducing size of map icon image